# How an I remove a cell from a Table in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

How an I remove a cell from a Table in Google Docs?  I'm trying to fix formatting of a table where I converted from Word.

[image: Heres what it looks like]

I would like it aligned properly like this table:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove cell or merge them? Can you provide an expected output from the picture you've provided?

Comment: @JasonE. See addition. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the docs as well? If it contains sensitive data, you can just include the header with 1 or 2 additional rows.

Comment: @JasonE. Thanks anyway. I just copied from the other table. I assume this can occur if you convert from Word.